Using less selector :not() in a :hover
<div class="row selectable">
       <div class="col-sm-1 notSelectable">
          First line with a delete button
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-11">
          The content that should be highlighted on hover
       </div>
    </div>

I want to be able to make a whole line of a list highligted except for the columns that are marked with a special class. The .less code I'm trying to use looks something like this
.selectable{
    &:hover:not(.notSelectable) {
        background-color: @hoverSelectColor;
    }
}

For some reason, I can only get the whole line highlighted when hovering. It does not exclude the notSelectable column. Any suggestions?
Is this because I combine both hover() and not() ?
I use bootstrap

Just add your class to the div or span element which you want to trigger the hover - like here:
<template>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-1">
      <span>First line with a delete button</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-11">
      <span class="hover-span">The content that should be highlighted on hover</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.hover-span:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>

Note: If you want a text while hovering look at Bootstrap-Tooltips!
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/
